# Does the column return matter in a WHERE EXISTS subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In this [SQL EXISTS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_exists.asp) operator tutorial has the following syntax for

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE condition);
```

Does the `column_name` in the select statement of the subquery matter? From other answers it seems like `0`, `1`, `*`, some arbitrary column name(s) have been used.

Comment: It does not matter.

Comment: Please read the real docs: [Since the result depends only on whether any rows are returned, and not on the contents of those rows, the output list of the subquery is normally unimportant.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS:~:text=Since%20the%20result%20depends%20only%20on%20whether%20any%20rows%20are%20returned%2C%20and%20not%20on%20the%20contents%20of%20those%20rows%2C%20the%20output%20list%20of%20the%20subquery%20is%20normally%20unimportant.)

Comment: Doesn't matter, it's not used. I always use the value 42, since 42 is the answer to the “ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything,”. In PostgreSQL you can also leave it empty, just `SELECT FROM table_name `

Comment: Huh. TIL. I _thought_ it mostly didn't matter, but that it _could_ matter if ALL of the values returned were NULL... that is, you had to have some kind of non-NULL result in at least one row from the subquery for the EXISTS() operation to be true. Thankfully I've never relied on that behavior, but I have gone through extra work to make sure to avoid it ;)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn [`select exists(select null);`](https://dbfiddle.uk/c1h-frzR) yields `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`EXISTS` section of Subquery Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) doc:

> The subquery will generally only be executed long enough to determine whether at least one row is returned, not all the way to completion.

> Since the result depends only on whether any rows are returned, and **not on the contents** of those rows, the output list of the subquery is normally unimportant.

Not only does it not matter, [since version 9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/release-9-4.html#AEN124237) it doesn't even have to be there:

> Allow [`SELECT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-select.html) to have an empty target list (Tom Lane)

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3LbX3Bpx):

```
CREATE TABLE table_name AS SELECT 'hello' AS "column_name", 
                                   true   AS "condition"  ;
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM table_name WHERE condition);
```

| column_name |
| --- |
| hello |

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` checks for the existence of **rows** in the subquery, not columns in it. Rows with anything will work. Even empty rows with no columns.

Answer (score -1):

It does not matter.

If you look at the source, you will see that PostgreSQL removes the `SELECT` list in such subqueries. A short, standard conforming way is to use a constant like

```
EXISTS (SELECT 42 FROM ...)
```

If I don't have to write standard conforming code, I prefer the even shorter

```
EXISTS (SELECT FROM ...)
```